# Passing value from HTML to XSLT using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have a XML which has order with fields id, name, qty and price.
I'm trying to create a page that takes the ID as input from the user and searches that in 
the XML and display the desired values. Have added this in my XML but it wasn't allowing me below ""

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="Order.xsl"?>
<orders>
       <order>
             <id>1</id>
             <name>A</name>
             <qty>5</qty>
             <rate>10</rate>
       </order>
</orders>
```

XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        function searchAcct()
          {
            AcctNum = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;

          }
     </script>
  <body>
     <form>
       Enter Account Num# : <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1"></input>
       <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="searchAcct()"></input>
     </form>    
     <xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
        <xsl:if test="id = AcctNum">
            <xsl:value-of select="name"></xsl:value-of>
            <xsl:value-of select="price"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:if>
     </xsl:for-each>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm new to the XML and XSLT so might have coded something wrong... please correct me.

Comment: This is not the correct approach, I am afraid. You are generating HTML from XML using XSLT, but as soon as the HTML is generated, the XSLT will effectively be forgotten about. The HTML will be processed by the browser no differently to if it was typed out by hand in a text editor. JavaScript cannot interact with the XSLT in the way you have shown. One approach you could take is render out all `order` items as hidden `DIV` tags, with an `id` attribute based on the order id, and then use javascript to show the relevant div based on id they enter in the text box.

Comment: Hi Tim... thanks for your response. This makes one thing clear to me that when I try to execute the HTML from XML the XSLT property will be forgotten. Since I'm quite new to these technology can you help me elaborating the DIV tag concept with an id attribute. If time permits you... meanwhile I'll try digging more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, JavaScript cannot interact with the XSLT in the way you have shown. As soon as the HTML is generated by the XSLT, the XSLT is effectively forgotten about and the HTML will be processed by the browser no differently to if it was typed out by hand in a text editor.

If you are using the `xml-stylesheet` directive in the XML to transform it, one approach you could take is to render out all order items as DIV tags, with an id attribute based on the order id and but with a style attribute set to hide them. Then use javascript to show the relevant div based on id they enter in the text box.

As a starter, try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" doctype-public="XSLT-compat" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showAcct()
          {
            var id = document.getElementById("textbox1").value;
            document.getElementById("orderDiv_" + id).style.display = "block";
          }
        </script>
        <body>
            <form>
            Enter Account Num# : <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1" />
            <input type="button" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Show" onclick="showAcct()" />
            </form>    
            <xsl:for-each select="orders/order">
                <div id="orderDiv_{id}" style="display:none">
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                    <br />
                    <xsl:value-of select="price" />
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is far from complete though. It does not hide any previous order it has shown. It also doesn't validate the value entered in the text box actually exists, but it may give you a start.

Comment: Tim.. thanks a ton! This works perfectly and provides me a insight into xml-stylesheet. I'll surely now take the things forward from here.